# ¿Cómo puedo saber si el elemento guardado en una lista es un string o un decimal o número?

Tags: c#, string, lista, float

Tengo una lista de tipo string en donde necesito ver que datos dados por el usuario son carácteres y cuáles son decimales... leyendo intenté creando una función booleana, pero cuando el carácter no puede pasarse a un decimal me da error. Este es mi código:

```
for (int posicion = 0; posicion < cont; posicion++)
            {

                bool conv = float.TryParse(lista[posicion], out tipo);
                if (conv == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El número es: " +tipo);
                }
                else if (conv == false)
                {
                     MessageBox.Show("La palabra es: " +lista[posicion]);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que en tu lista tienes estos elementos:

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>();
        lista.Add("Hola");
        lista.Add("5");
        lista.Add("3.5");
```

Recorre la lista y utiliza esto (en este ejemplo utilice un foreach) :

```
bool tipoDato = int.TryParse(item, out entero) || double.TryParse(item, out esdecimal);
```

Y ya solo evaluas con:

```
if (tipoDato)
            {
                //Entero o decimal
            }
            else
            {
                //Cadena Texto
            }
```